# VS2008 plugin error/warning markers like in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2008, plugins

I'm a C# developer who has temporarily shifted to Android development for a few projects and I'm  loving Eclipse so far!

I was wondering, does VS2008 have a plugin to enable eclipse like line markers for errors / warnings / TODO's (the little line marker bars at the right side of eclipse window)? That would really be useful in VS2008!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

I haven't used Eclispse yet, but ReSharper shows lines on the right side of the screen to indicate errors, TODO's, etc.